# Where to tell Chrome team of an error in their documentation?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, download, filenames

I clicked on the "Questions?" link from their extension development pages, and it took me here. I couldn't see any other link that suggested communication with anyone.

The problem I have is within chrome.downloads information page - http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html

In the DownloadOptions object definition, it has the property 'filename', which it defines as:

```
filename ( optional string )
    A file path relative to the Downloads directory to contain the downloaded file.
```

Except, this only lets you change the destination name of the file, and does not allow modifying the path name. As soon as an forward or backslash is used, it returns "I'm afraid I can't do that" to the console.

So, the implementation is at odds with the documentation, and I'm confused about if it's worth pursuing my project at all or if I should abandon ship now.

If anyone can point me somewhere to get an answer on this, I'd be very grateful! Thank you.

Comment: Well, as said by the disclaimer on the page you linked to, that API is still under development, so they might not have their documentation up to date with their latest 'fiddling around' with that function.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation source has since been fixed. (I'd link to downloads.idl, but "You need at least 10 rep to post more than 2 links." :-? ) I'll see about updating that URL.

`chrome.downloads.download({filename})` does not currently support subdirectories, but we plan on fixing that soon.

In the meantime, you can use [onDeterminingFilename](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/downloads.html#event-onDeterminingFilename) to use subdirectories relative to the default Downloads directory. You cannot place downloads outside of that directory for security reasons.

In the future, feel free to file a bug at http://crbug.com/new. That will result in an email directly to the maintainer of the API (me!).